Как в telebot получить настройки конфиденциальности пользователя?
Требуется получить настройки конфиденциальности пользователя, пользующимся ботом на telebot, а именно параметр "Пересылка сообщений". На сайте API телеграма есть класс, позволяющий это сделать ChatFullInfo
Параметр класса has_private_forwards
Подскажите, как это реализовано в telebot? Такого или подобного класса не нашел
